# Multiplying textfield value with select valaue

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I multiply a value in a textfield with a value of a select list?

I have folowing HTML Code:

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#myForm').on('keyup', 'input', function() {
    var iSum = 0;
    $('#myForm input').each( function() {
       iSum = iSum + parseFloat($(this).val());
    });       
    $('#calculateSum').html(iSum);
});
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
<input type="text" placeholder="Room length" /><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Room width" />
<br>
<select>
  <option value="type-1">Type 1 (150,00€/m²)</option>
  <option value="type-2">Type 2 (155,00€/m²)</option>
</select><br>
  <div>
      <label for="calculateSum">Sum is</label>
      <span id="calculateSum">0</span> /m²
  </div>
  </form>
```

I want to multiply the value of the select-list with the result of the multiplication of the textfields. So is should be room length x room width x eg. type-1

Comment: You want to multiply the value of the select list - either `type-1` or `type-2` by a numerical value... how exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function calculate() {
 var iSum = 1;
 $('#myForm input').each( function() {
  iSum *= parseFloat($(this).val());
 });       
 $('#calculateSum').html(iSum);
 var selectedValue = Number($("#values").val());
 $('#calculateValue').html(iSum * selectedValue);
}
$(document).ready( function() {
 $('#myForm input, #values').on('keyup change select', function() {
  calculate();
 });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
<input type="text" placeholder="Room length" /><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Room width" />
<br>
<select id="values">
  <option value="150.00">Type 1 (150,00€/m²)</option>
  <option value="155.00">Type 2 (155,00€/m²)</option>
</select><br>
  <div>
      <label for="calculateSum">Sum is</label>
      <span id="calculateSum">0</span> /m² <br />
      Totla: <span id="calculateValue">0</span> €
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/kq3ugctn/1/

```js
updateCalc = function(){
  var iSum = 1;
  $('#myForm input').each( function() {
    if(isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
      iSum *= 0;
    } else {
      iSum *= parseFloat($(this).val());
    }    
  });       
  iSum *= parseFloat($('select option:selected').data('value'));
  $('#calculateSum').html(iSum);
}

$('#myForm').on('keyup', 'input', function() {
  updateCalc();
});

$('select').on('change', function(){
  updateCalc();   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Room length" /><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Room width" />
  <br/>
  <select>
    <option value="type-1" data-value="15000" selected>Type 1 (150,00€/m²)</option>
    <option value="type-2" data-value="15500">Type 2 (155,00€/m²)</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <div>
    <label for="calculateSum">Sum is</label>
    <span id="calculateSum">0</span> /m²
  </div>
</form>
```

**Solution explanation**

`updateCalc` method will be called twice

- When an `input textbox` updates
- Select option changes.

If the value is not entered into the `input` textbox` then it will be considered as **0**

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer to this will be:

```
     <form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="roomLength" placeholder="Room length" onchange="calculateCost();" /><br>
    <input type="text" id="roomHeight" placeholder="Room width" onchange="calculateCost();" />
    <br>
    <select name="rate" id="rate" onchange="calculateCost();">
      <option value="150.00">Type 1 (150,00€/m²)</option>
      <option value="155.00">Type 2 (155,00€/m²)</option>
    </select><br>
      <div>
          <label for="calculateArea">Area is</label>
          <span id="calculateArea">0</span>m²

          <label for="calculateCost">Cost is</label>
          &euro;<span id="calculateCost">0</span> 
      </div>
 </form>

        <script>
             function calculateCost() {
                var area = $('#roomLength').val() * $('#roomHeight').val();

                $('#calculateArea').html(area);


               var rate = $('select[name=rate]').val();
               var cost = area * rate;

               $('#calculateCost').html(cost); 

            }
    </script>
```